# Bug Merge Using Svn

Tags: svn, merge

How to merge bug occurred in one branch to another ..

Example : There is bug id :1010 (this is fixed using some 2 files) Under branch-5 i want to merge same files(2 files) to branch-3

Can anybody please help out?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the process is something like this. Say you are merging some commits made in branch-5 into branch-3. So in branch-3 if you could select Merge from a range of revisions. Then in the URL of the branch where the revisions are present you would select the revisions where you committed the two files, and then merge. There is also a Test-merge option available in TortoiseSVN. The process should be similar in RabbitVCS Svn on Ubuntu. Sorry, never used a command line for SVN, though I think with this knowledge you could look it up on the SVN docs to find the command line equivalent. Hope this helps !

Comment: revision no of branch-5 is 2030(ie bug fixed under this revision no) , i want to merge to revision no 2045(this revision no got created when i was adding my branch)

Comment: I dint get you, dint you want to merge one set of revision from a branch into another branch ? My answer above was to do that. I dont think you can merge a revision into another revision. As in you cannot change revision no 2045. You can make a merge of the revision 2030 and the code changes will reflect, but you cant change an existing revision.

Comment: can i do something like this : svn merge -r 2030 : 2045 path/branch3

Comment: hate to say but sorry, I have never used command line for SVN(not even on Ubuntu). :(